# after wordpress site hacked only displaying white page

Tags: wordpress, rackspace-cloud

Recently a clients site got hacked on Rackspace and since then I have been trying to recover certain items on the site.

I have cleaned everything up and did a framework upgrade.

Now when I am trying to install something new, make changes, or simply post an update it renders a white page after success...

I have disabled all my plugins and still the same issue.

Have any of you experienced this before and what are some of the steps you could give to recover this...

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have managed to find some good tips that has helped.

Ultimately disabled all plugins, reinstalled wordpress, there were some issues in the following files.

`wp-config.php`, `pluggable.php` and `class.wp-scripts.php` - all these missed a closing `?>`

And make sure that your themes `functions.php` file doesn't have any whitespace.